# Parameter For All Primitive Types of Java?

Tags: java, primitive-types

I have this function;

```
static public void Print(Object[] arr) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        System.out.println(i + " => " + arr[i]);
}
```

I want to use that for every primitive type array. Isn't there any way to do that without overriding it for every primitive type?

Note: This is just an example function. I want to know the technique if there is one.

Comment: You cannot do this for primitives. If your design allows it I would highly recommend you use the object versions instead.

Comment: @VinceEmigh - because primitives are not objects, and there is no language level support for 'naked' auto-boxing from primitive types to object ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Array element types are not wrapped, `Object[]` formal parameter is not applicable for e.g. `int[]` actual parameter. You have to write one method per primitive type, as in [`java.util.Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html). Ugly, but the only way.

Answer (score 4):

Primitive arrays are Objects in java, so you could use `Object`-type as the parameter (note, not an array of Objects, but just Object). The problem is, you'd still need to cast it to correct type to be able to iterate the array.

```
public class ArrayTest
{
    public void paramTest(Object args)
    {       
        if(args instanceof int[])
        {
            System.out.println("int-array");
        }

        if(args instanceof float[])
        {
            System.out.println("float-array");
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        paramTest(new int[5]);
        paramTest(new float[5]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
int-array
float-array
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's called generics. Generics are - like templates in c++ - a variable type.

Take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Comment: Thanks. That worked for me; 
static public <E extends Object> void Print(E[] arr)

Comment: It... does? What Java version? Could you show the calling code, please? From the linked wiki page: "`public <T> T[] toArray(T... elements) {
   return elements;
}` In such cases you can't use native types either, ex:
   Integer[] array = toArray(1,2,3,4,5);" - I get a "not applicable" for `int[]` and that signature.

Comment: Oh sorry, it's not working with int[] type parameter, only Integer[]. You are right. I can't change whole struct for that. I think it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java generics like this to achieve what you want, here `Number` is `java.lang.Number`:

```
public static <T extends Number> void print(T[] arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i + " => " + arr[i]);
    }
}
```

But this will work only for array of **Primitive wrapper classes** and not for Primitive arrays.

Comment: This won't work if you try to pass in a 'raw' primitive array, like calling  `print(new float[5])` -> 'not applicable for the arguments (float[])'. Primitive arrays are not autoboxed.

Comment: @esaj, Agreed. Updated my answer by mentioning this. Thanks.