# What is the umbrella name for number based primitive types in Java?

Tags: java, methods

[image]I'm creating a backup set of methods that i can recycle. I learnt to use Object for some  but my next method can only work with number. Is their a var name i can use instaed of having to create separate method for int, double, short, float, long and byte. Here is the method for int:

```
public static int getMax(int[] set){
    int out = set[0];
    for(int i=1; i<set.length; i++){
        out = Math.max(out, set[i]);
    }
    return out;
}
```

when i try using the instanceOf solution from [Parameter For All Primitive Types of Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240370/parameter-for-all-primitive-types-of-java) it runs an incompatible error although it seems fine with Integer. Also these method is almost the same as creating separate method for each primitive type.

And when i tried primitive type with Arraylist, the output is ArrayList and cannot be cast to int or short. like:

```
int thik = (int)getMax(R[] set); //runs error
```

Comment: You could use `Number`, but this might introduce limitations you might not want

Comment: @kbluue My thoughts here are that you can consider having multiple overloaded methods to handle the various primitive types.