# How can I make a Java method accept arrays of different (primitive) variable types?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, types

I want to write a simple method to print an array - looking like an array -  with its elements in the terminal, independent of whether it is an int[], boolean[], String[], double[] etc.

The `String info` parameter is just meant to output some answer phrase with the array shown, like `"The wanted array is { .... }"`.

I am aware that in Java

- unspecified parameter types should be handled with extreme care
- primitive variable types cannot easily be used with generic data types
- the usual answer for accepting different parameter types is overloading (which I finally did),

but the only difference between the different versions of the method `printArray(...)` is the variable type of the array handed over in the parameter list.

I also tried to hand over an `object[] pArray` as a parameter, but then it would only accept integer arrays, or give a runtime error message.

A similar concept is addressed in the answers to the former post [Parameter For All Primitive Types of Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240370/parameter-for-all-primitive-types-of-java), but - although it is pretty much the same question - the answers don't give solutions for arrays of simple primitives. They only answer

- ways to find out, which parameter type was used, or
- are limited to object types (including wrapper classes) or Number-objects, but which both don't solve my problem.

Looking at this the mantra "avoid code duplication" seems to be so obviously violated that I believe there must be a better solution.

Can anyone help me with this?    Here is the code:

```
void printArray(String info, boolean[] pArray)
{
    String arrayString = "";

    if (pArray.length > 0){
        arrayString = "{ " + pArray[0];

        for (int a = 1; a < pArray.length; a++){
            arrayString = arrayString + ", " + pArray[a];
        }
        arrayString = arrayString + " }";
    } else {
        arrayString = "{}";
    }

    System.out.println(info + arrayString + "\n");
}

void printArray(String info, int[] pArray)
{
    String arrayString = "";

    if (pArray.length > 0){
        arrayString = "{ " + pArray[0];

        for (int a = 1; a < pArray.length; a++){
            arrayString = arrayString + ", " + pArray[a];
        }
        arrayString = arrayString + " }";
    } else {
        arrayString = "{}";
    }

    System.out.println(info + arrayString + "\n"); 
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [`java.util.Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html). You will see that even the people who created Java cannot avoid such code duplication with primitives, at least with Java as it is today. There is something being worked on called [Project Valhalla](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/valhalla/) that will allow generics over primitive types in some future version of Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. But the only common ancestral type for all arrays<sup>**1**</sup> is `Object`. You can use that and [`java.lang.reflect.Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html). Also since `printArray` has no state, you might as well make it `static` like

```
static void printArray(String info, Object pArray) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(info);
    int len = Array.getLength(pArray);
    if (len > 0) {
        sb.append("{ ").append(Array.get(pArray, 0));
        for (int a = 1; a < len; a++) {
            sb.append(", ").append(Array.get(pArray, a));
        }
        sb.append(" }");
    } else {
        sb.append("{}");
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

I tested it like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[] bArr = { true, true, false, false };
    int[] iArr = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    printArray("boolean[]", bArr);
    printArray("int[]", iArr);
}
```

Which outputs

```
boolean[]{ true, true, false, false }
int[]{ 0, 1, 2, 3 }
```

<sup>**1**</sup><sub>Both primitive and reference types. `Object obj = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };` and `Object obj = new String[] { "Hello", "World" };` are both valid. All arrays are `Object`s in Java.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer - works great!

Just for a clear understanding: I am not creating an array of objects, but the array itself is the undefined object, and only when I call a method of "Array"-class like `Array.getLength(pArray)` this object is interpreted as an array?

Comment: Every reference type (including array) is a subtype of `Object`. Even `Object[]`. `Object obj = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };` is perfectly legal. As is `Object obj = new String[] { "Hello", "World" };`

Comment: `printArray` didn't have a state since I only tested it in Visual Studio Code. In a real class I would make it private or protected, depending on the project. I also liked your hint on using *StringBuilder` - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Stream from an array of primitives, and then create an array of Objects from the Stream. This is one example.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayPrinter {
    
    public static void printArray(Object[] arr) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sb.append(i == 0 ? arr[i] : " " + arr[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        Integer[] objs = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
        printArray(objs);
    }
}
```

It's also fine to just have multiple versions of a method, one for an int array, one for a boolean array, one for a String array, et cetera. This strategy is called method overloading, and it's common. You can see examples of method overloading in the java.lang.Math class. The methods `java.lang.Math.abs`, `java.lang.Math.max`, and `java.lang.Math.min` are overloaded for different parameter types.